# Listening for other URL schemes in Safari Web Extension

Tags: ios, iphone, url-scheme

I'm trying to develop a small project to learn Safari web extension development. For that purpose, I've downloaded [Developing a Safari Web Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/developing_a_safari_web_extension?language=objc)from Apple. In there, I saw we can define matches for urls. For my project, I want to know if we can also catch events for other url schemes.

I added `"itms-ui://*"` to manifest.json file:

```
 "content_scripts": [{
        "js": [ "content.js" ],
        "matches": [ "*://example.com/*","itms-ui://*" ]
    }],
```

But giving this url to safari did not seem to cause a breakpoint to hit.
Platform is iOS 16.3.1

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!